# Spring SPEL evaluation throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to compile expression with elvis operator

Tags: spring, spring-el

can someone explain why is exception thrown in this case:

```
@Test
public void spel_elvis_operator_test() {
    String time1 = "time1";
    String time2 = "time2";

    String spelExpression = String.format("get('%s') ?: get('%s')", time1, time2);

    Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser(new SpelParserConfiguration(SpelCompilerMode.IMMEDIATE, null))
            .parseExpression(spelExpression);

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put(time1, 1000L);
    data.put(time2, 2000L);

    // execute first time - interprets the expression
    assertThat(expression.getValue(new StandardEvaluationContext(data), Long.class)).isEqualTo(1000L);

    data.remove(time1);

    // execute second time - tries to compile expression
    assertThat(expression.getValue(new StandardEvaluationContext(data), Long.class)).isEqualTo(2000L);
}
```

When I run this test, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

at org.springframework.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1501)
at org.springframework.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1478)
at org.springframework.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(MethodWriter.java:1516)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelCompiler.createExpressionClass(SpelCompiler.java:176)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelCompiler.compile(SpelCompiler.java:105)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.compileExpression(SpelExpression.java:467)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.checkCompile(SpelExpression.java:437)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:300)
```

I am trying to use compiled SPEL expressions for dynamic data filtering and I feel like I am playing Russian roulette...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. Looks like this type of expression is not compilable, therefore fallback to the interpretation mode has to be used.

This one works for me:

```
String spelExpression = String.format("get('%s') != null ? get('%s') : get('%s')", time1, time1, time2);
```

I mean I use there classical Java ternary operator instead of elvis.

Feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR